# MMQGIS Geocode is failing in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, geocoding, error, nominatim, mmqgis

I am facing troubles geocoding the CSV file in QGIS 3 with MMQGIS (OpenStreetMap).

Images below are showing my workflow and the problem that I am encountering.

[image: Example_Step1]
[image: Example_Step2]
[image: Example_Step3]

I am getting the following error:

```
Failure connecting to nominatim: <urlopen error [SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)>: 0 
addresses geocoded
```

I'm using a Mac with OS 10.14.1 (18B75) and my Internet connection is stable.

These are my QGIS specifications:

[image: Tech_specification]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I have found the solution.

As the error suggests: the SSL in Python is not correctly installed.

If you go to `/application/python(your version)` and then click `"Install Certificates.command"` everything shall work.

Comment: How do I do this on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

To implement the solution which consist in execute the install certificates.command, is really important to check before if you have the **PyQt5** module in version 5.10. A quick check could be: `pip3 install PyQt5`

If you don't have this one installed (Since I had the same problem), my solution adopted was: `pip3 install pyqt5==5.10`

Also, we have to run the install certificates commando with **sudo**. So, in other words you have to type in the terminal of your computer `sudo [address in your pc where is allocated the install certificates.command]`