# MMQGIS SSL Certificate Verify Failed

Tags: qgis, geocoding, mmqgis

I am new to coding with QGIS.

However, when trying to geocode with MMQGIS I am confronted with:

> Failure connecting to API: urlopen error [SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
>   local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>.

I have tried redownloading python, updating qgis, making sure I hit "Install Certificates.command", all to no avail. I have seen [MMQGIS Geocode is failing in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308338/mmqgis-geocode-is-failing-in-qgis-3), but the answers there are having no effect on my situation. Running QGIS 3.10, but have tried on 3.6 as well.

Comment: What are the “accepted solutions” that you have already tried?  What Q&As did they come from?

Comment: @PolyGeo I have tried what is suggested here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308338/mmqgis-geocode-is-failing-in-qgis-3

Answer (score 2):

I have had the exact same problem for months and did the same things that you did. However, today, I discovered that there is a new version of MMQGIS out. I just updated the plugin and have been able to successfully geocode the addresses I have.