# Failure connecting to API - Geocoding using MMQGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, api, mmqgis, ssl

I'm very new to GIS and am trying to geocode a list of addresses of some OpenData in QGIS using MMQGIS....however when I go to run MMQGIS Geocode function with my .csv. I keep getting this error and similar ones.

`Failure connecting to API: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>`

I've read the different forums and updated my Shell Profile and Install Certificates in Python. If its relevant I use MacOS and QGIS 3.10 and have Python 3.8 Installed..

Comment: Can you post your url call.

Comment: I'm using the MMQGIS plugin directly in QGIS, so I don't have access to the code to modify as you've suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code:
`response = requests.get(url, verify=False)`

Without `verify=false` the inherent function of `request.get` is to verify your ssl cert since you are requesting over https.

If you find that you want to `verify=true` then you will need more code. [This article](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/) will be helpful.

Comment: I'm using the MMQGIS plugin directly in QGIS, so I don't have access to the code to modify as you've suggested

Comment: Check out this older post - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308338/mmqgis-geocode-is-failing-in-qgis-3

Comment: Dang even those fixes didn't resolve it